# How to combine a collection of tracing subscribers in one?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

Let's say I have a function that returns a `Vec<Box<dyn Subscriber>>` and I want to combine them into a single one to be set as the default subscriber.
How to do this?

I'm trying to do something like this, but I cannot make the types match:

```rust
pub fn init_log(subscribers: Vec<Box<dyn Subscriber>>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    use tracing_subscriber::prelude::*;
    let mut layers: Vec<Box<dyn Layer<dyn Subscriber>>> = Vec::new();

    for subscriber in subscribers.iter().drain(..) {
        let layer: Box<dyn Layer<dyn Subscriber>> =
          Box::new(tracing_subscriber::layer::Identity::new().with_subscriber(subscriber));

        layers.push(layer);
    }

    let init_layer: Box<dyn Layer<dyn Subscriber>> =
        Box::new(tracing_subscriber::layer::Identity::new());

    let acc_subscriber: Layered<Box<dyn Layer<dyn Subscriber>>, _> =
        tracing_subscriber::fmt().finish().with(init_layer);
    
    let composed = layers
        .drain(..)
        .into_iter()
        .fold(acc_subscriber, |acc, layer| acc.with(layer));
    
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(composed);

    Ok(())
}
```

```bash
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<dyn tracing::Subscriber>: tracing::Subscriber` is not satisfied
  --> jormungandr\src\settings\logging.rs:97:85
   |
97 |                 Box::new(tracing_subscriber::layer::Identity::new().with_subscriber(subscriber));
   |                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `tracing::Subscriber` is not implemented for `Box<dyn tracing::Subscriber>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is fundamentally at odds with what a `Subscriber` is tasked with handling. I think the [module documentation](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/layer/index.html) for `Layer`s puts it clearly:

> The `Subscriber` trait in `tracing-core` represents the complete set of functionality required to consume `tracing` instrumentation. This means that a single `Subscriber` instance is a self-contained implementation of a complete strategy for collecting traces; but it also means that the `Subscriber` trait cannot easily be composed with other `Subscriber`s.
>
> In particular, `Subscriber`s are responsible for generating span IDs and assigning them to spans. Since these IDs must uniquely identify a span within the context of the current trace, this means that there may only be a single `Subscriber` for a given thread at any point in time — otherwise, there would be no authoritative source of span IDs.
>
> On the other hand, the majority of the `Subscriber` trait’s functionality is composable: any number of subscribers may observe events, span entry and exit, and so on, provided that there is a single authoritative source of span IDs. The `Layer` trait represents this composable subset of the `Subscriber` behavior; it can observe events and spans, but does not assign IDs.

So if at all possible, try to generalize your logging configuration over `Layer`s instead of `Subscriber`s. There is even a [`impl Layer for Vec<L> where L: Layer`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/layer/trait.Layer.html#impl-Layer%3CS%3E-for-Vec%3CL%3E) implementation already.

I think this expressibility and composiblity is the reason why most [Related Crates](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/#related-crates) are implemented as `Layer`s instead of `Subscriber`s. Even some of those listed as "implements a subscriber" use layers (like tracing-gelf or tracing-forest).

Comment: Yeah, I did it at that time using layers. But I recall a problem with the types themselves as well so it wasn't possible to use them, somehow it compiled but didn't worked. Then had to use a different direction. But it was quite some time ago, so I don't remember how did I actually solved it.